# SQL Server Management Studio make default date 5 days from now

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

I am working on a database and I need to make the default value for a date column to be 5 days from the current date.

Would using `getdate() + 5` work?

I'm using the GUI at the moment.

Would a query like this work?

```
ALTER TABLE Order 
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Order DEFAULT GETDATE()+5 FOR DateofOrder
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just adding a `+5` to a `DATETIME` is kinda unclear what you're adding to that date & time - 5 years? 5 months? 5 days? Why not 5 hours? 5 minutes? Use the `DATEADD` function and specify that you want to add **days** to your `DATETIME` value ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yout can tryout `DateAdd` function for adding days to date

Example

```
DATEADD(day,1,@datetimevar/column)
```

try like this

```
create table t(
  i int,
  d datetime default (dateadd(day,5,getdate()))
)
```